# How to know indicator value change in circulargauge in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

when i change the indicator value i want to get the value of indicator. from that i want to set other indicator value. is there any event for indicator value change in dojo. i have used below code but its not working. alert is not working.

```
    makeGauge2 = function() {
    GaugeInPounds = new dojox.gauges.GlossySemiCircularGauge({
        background : [ 255, 255, 255, 0 ],
        title : 'Value',
        id : "glossyGauge2",
        width : 300,
        height : 300,
        max:200,
        majorTicksInterval:20,
        minorTicksInterval:10
    }, dojo.byId("GaugeInPounds"));
    GaugeInPounds.startup();


};
dojo.ready(makeGauge);
dojo.ready(makeGauge2);
//var gauge1 = dijit.byId("GaugeInPounds");
dijit.byId("GaugeInPounds").on("startEditing", function(event){
    alert(event.indicator.value);
    console.log(event.indicator.value);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one this code will help you.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<!-- dojo/javascript will go here -->
<script src="js/dojo-release-1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Load the widget parser and mobile base
require([ "dojox/mobile/parser", "dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/connect",
        "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojo", "dojox/gauges/GlossySemiCircularGauge" ],

function(parser, ready, connect) {
    // Parse the page for widgets!
    parser.parse();

    var glossyCircular = new dojox.gauges.GlossySemiCircularGauge({
        background: [255, 255, 255, 0],
        title: 'Value',
        id: "glossyGauge",
        width: 300,
        height: 300,

    }, dojo.byId("SemiCircularGauge"));
    connect.connect(glossyCircular, "onValueChanged", function(){
          console.log(glossyCircular.value);
    }); 
    glossyCircular.startup();

});
</script>
</head>
<body >
     <div id="SemiCircularGauge" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```